# Capture Text between the start of one tag and beginning of another?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following string:

```
<<John Smith, Youtube>> 
I'm having a great day today 
<<Jane Doe, Google>> 
I'm going to the gym later 
<<Speaker>>
Time for people to speak 
<<Beff Jezos>> 
Buy something from my online shop. You might like it
```

You can load in this string via the following script command in python:

```
string = '''<<John Smith, Youtube>> 
I'm having a great day today 
<<Jane Doe, Google>> 
I'm going to the gym later 
<<Speaker>>
Time for people to speak 
<<Beff Jezos>> 
Buy something from my online shop. You might like it'''
```

loading python packages:

```
import re
```

I'm trying to find a way to capture the following information: I want to extract out the information between the start of **<<** and all of the proceeding text up until the next **<<**

e.g. this means a way of extracting the following strings:

```
string1: John Smith, Youtube>> 
I'm having a great day today 

string2: Jane Doe, Google>> 
I'm going to the gym later 

string3: Speaker>>
Time for people to speak 

string4: Beff Jezos>> 
Buy something from my online shop. You might like it
```

The output can be a list or a named dictionary with Key value pairs, the values in between the tags << and >> are identifiers, but not always unique some do repeat.

Any help is appreciated - current regex has got me this far: `/(?=<<)(.*)(?=<<)/gm`

New string:

```
Welcome to the first meeting today between Yotube, Google and Amazon  Special guest speaker today is Beff Jezos 
<<John Smith, Youtube>>  I'm having a great day today  
<<Jane Doe, Google>>  I'm going to the gym later  
<<Speaker>> Time for people to speak  
<<Beff Jezos>>  Buy something from my online shop. You might like it
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this gives you the result you are wishing for?

```
import re

string = '''<<John Smith, Youtube>> 
I'm having a great day today 
<<Jane Doe, Google>> 
I'm going to the gym later 
<<Speaker>>
Time for people to speak 
<<Beff Jezos>> 
Buy something from my online shop. You might like it'''

pattern = r'<<(.*?)>>\s*(.*?)\s*(?=(?:<<|$))'
matches = re.findall(pattern, string, re.DOTALL)

result = []
for match in matches:
    identifier = match[0]
    content = match[1]
    result.append((identifier, content))

print(result)
```

So what do they do?:

`<<(.*?)>>` captures the content between `<<` and `>>`

`\s*` it's about the whitespace characters

`(.*?)` captures the content after `>>` and `<<`.

edit: Tim's answer is a bit simpler and explained better.

Comment: Does this work regardless of the string preceding these? I've added an updated the string

Comment: `[('John Smith, Youtube', "I'm having a great day today"), ('Jane Doe, Google', "I'm going to the gym later"), ('Speaker', 'Time for people to speak'), ('Beff Jezos', 'Buy something from my online shop. You might like it')]` is the answer for the new string. Is it what you want?

Comment: Yes - that output is the one I'm looking for - it looks like a zip object was applied to the list elements?

Comment: yeah. I tried to "couple" the two results

Answer (score 0):

We can do a regex find all search as follows:

```
matches = re.findall(r'<<(.*?)(?=\s*<<|$)', string, flags=re.S)
print(matches)

["John Smith, Youtube>> \nI'm having a great day today",
 "Jane Doe, Google>> \nI'm going to the gym later",
 'Speaker>>\nTime for people to speak',
 'Beff Jezos>> \nBuy something from my online shop. You might like it']
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `<<`
- `(.*?)` match and capture all content until reaching the nearest
- `(?=\s*<<|$)` optional whitespace followed by `<<` start of the next tag OR
  end of the input

Note that we do the regex search in dot all mode, as indicated by the `re.S` flag, so that `.*` will match across lines.